# Difference between base_price and base_original_price

Tags: api, sales-order

What is the difference between `base_price` and `base_original_price` in Sales Orders object?

In which cases both these values differ?

I have noticed a difference between these values in two instances -

1) When there is a gift card added to the order

2) When "custom price" was used while creating the order

However, I'm not sure of the exact scenario.

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 3):

**Base original price :** excludes discounts, no currency conversion, may or may not include tax.

**Base price :** includes discounts, no currency conversion, may or may not include tax

Answer (score 2):

Price and base price depends on your store and currency.

Price is the value in the selected store currency

Base Price is the value in the default store currency.

Price and base price should have the same value if you have just one currency on your website.

Comment: Thanks @prince. 
However my question is not the difference between price & base_price. I want to know the difference between base_price and base_original_price. Both are base values. Could you please answer this?